# what are rdbms access methods and can I use thrift with rdbms?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, odbc, rdbms, thrift

I am reading professional nosql book,and there is a list of different nosql db access methods,but i dont know what are access method in rdbms?
odbc/jdbc and their drivers are counted as access methods?

or ado.net,linq to sql,entity frame work,are counted as access methods?

what is the difference between ado.net/linq to sql/entity frame work and odbc/jdbc,I mean they both are used to access databases,so how do they differ?

and my other question is why cant thrift/avro/rest/protobuf be used with rdbms,they are services,why are they just used with nosql dbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds pretty much like your other question, at least 75% of it :-)

> what is the difference between ado.net/linq to sql/entity frame work and odbc/jdbc, I mean they both are used to access databases,so how do they differ?

They differ in several ways. First, certain DBMS typically support only a few ways how to connect to them. Some less, some more, it heavily depends on the DBMS. Next, some of the methods you listed, like LINQ, are not available in all environments. For example, take some arbitrary programming language not based on .NET technology, and LINQ is no longer an option.

> and my other question is why cant thrift/avro/rest/protobuf be used with rdbms,they are services,

No, these are not services. They are mechanisms to do remote procedure calls. An RPC can be anything, including a DB query, but not limited to that. The DB can be considered a Service, and thrift/avro/rest/protobuf/etc. are the ways in which these services are made accessible to you. But again, each DBMS typically supports only a few selected ways. And some databases can only be accessed by a specific dedicated database client library, like ESENT.

> why are they just used with nosql dbs?

Because the DBMS does not support it.